# Even in a new project: Can't add script component because the script class cannot be found?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue where no matter what I get the error saying Can't add script component because script class cannot be found.

I suspect it was from importing an asset. I don't know how to undo whatever I did.
If I start a New Project it still gives me the error. So I cannot add any C# scripts.
It was working fine some time before I don't know exactly when it stopped. Just some time during importing assets.
I've tried reimporting all of the assets.
It's not in my code because I can create a new C# script and try to use it without making any changes and it still gives me the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the name of your script in your Assets is exactly the same as the class name at the top of your script :
public class YourScriptName : MonoBehaviour

Comment: Thanks, but they're all the exact same.

Comment: Is it the same with a new script ? With the `Add Component` in the inspector window ?

Comment: it actually does allow me to use the Add Component in the inspector window. But, any time I try to drag a script it gives me the error.

Comment: You can try to select the script in your Assets folder, click on the cog icon in the Inspector window and select Reset. Some people fix it like that. Otherwise you have no errors in the console ?